# jQuery .load() misunderstanding

Tags: jquery

The following function binds the events change and load for appearing text fields, but "load" doesnt work (change does).

The intention is that the value of the list field "showrow" is read out correctly after page reload for showing the correct amount of text field(s). The value is already stored (remembered) in the list field showrow by another function. Maybe I dont understand the event "load" and this is solved somehow else ..

```
 //Selection of the members 
    $('select.showrow').bind('change load', function() {
       $('#result').empty();
        $zaehler = 0;
        $.each(new Array(+this.value), function() {
            $zaehler = $zaehler+1;
            $('<div />', {
                html : '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-input form-control fieldgap" name="vorname'+$zaehler+'" id="vorname'+$zaehler+'"   placeholder="[[++vorname]]"></div>'
            }).appendTo('#result');

        });
```

Comment: The `load` event only applies to elements that load something from a URL.

Comment: Is there any other event which I could bind?